# Jest is not compiling typescript just-in-time

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

### The Problem

When I run `npx jest` after making a change to my code, it executes the tests against an older version of my code. When I run `npx tsc` and then run `npx jest` the latest version of my code is executed in the test.

As I understand it jest should run tests against the source code, not the built artifacts so this behaviour is unexpected.

### My Setup

#### jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/test'
  ],
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out",
    "test",
    "functionalTest"
  ]
}
```

#### Relevant package.json dependencies

```
...
    "@types/jest": "26.0.24",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.6",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
...
```